# What is the proper approach of initializing an object (Factory, Init, DI), design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, initialization, inversion-of-control

What is the best way to handle the next case:
We have a class, which is injecting some other class in a constructor. Constructor besides this injection has some other parameters.

```
class A
{
    constructor(B b, int x, int y);
}
```

Just because constructor has non-injectable values, which are different each time, we cannot rely on IOC no more and deal with them manually.

There's 2 ways:
1) Implement method Init(int x, int y), which will initialize our object with non-injectable properties and remove them from constructor, so IOC framework will handle it automatically
2) Create a factory, which will have a creator method for this object, and this method will accept x and y

1)

```
class A
{
    constructor(B b);
    init(int x, int y);
}
```

2)

```
class A
{
    constructor(B b, int x, int y);
}

class AFactory
{
   constructor(B b);
   createA(int x, int y)
   { return new A(b, x, y); }
}
```

Drawbacks of 1st way - we need to declare all initializable variables as nullable, because initialization is not guaranteed and we need to keep in mind to call init method.

Drawbacks of 2nd way - if object will have a lot of injections - we need to inject them to factory c-tor and pass them to a c-tor of creatable object

The most safe IMO is 2nd approach, as it is safer, than the 1st in terms of initialization guarantees, but it's not good enough

Maybe there's another way of doing it, or improving ways described above?

This question could be related in general to all languages and frameworks, but FYI I'm using plain typescript + inversify

@Update
@Steven Questions about solutions:
1) passing runtime data through method calls of the API
2) retrieving runtime data from specific abstractions that allow resolving runtime data

The first way can become tricky and uncomfortable, because class could have many methods, and all of them are dependent on runtime data passed to a constructor, so I will be forced to add that runtime data to every method's signature. That seems not too hard, but when these methods are used by another class methods, it will be required to add this runtime data to the caller method too, which could lead to the spreading and passing this runtime data all the way down to the end of chain call.

The second way can lead to creating a lot of abstractions if data is used in different part of applications and is unique for each part.

What would you recommend in this case?

Here's more detailed code:

Client code:

```
await this.switchToRunningState(context);

const authResult = await this.getAuthResult(context);

const executionResult = await this.execute(context, authResult);

await this.outputExecutionResult(context, executionResult);
```

The problem lays in auth result and execute
So, here's how I use auth result:

```
executor
{
    c-tor(authResult, executionClient) -> app logic
    ... some methods
}

executionClient
{
    c-tor(authResult, httpClientFactory) -> encapsulated 3rd party API http calls
    ... some methods
}

httpClientFactory
{
    create(authResult) -> httpClient with auth data in cookies
}
```

I came up with another solution: create some kind of storage abstraction with get and set methods. set method will be called instantly after auth and get method will be called at the end of this chain - httpClientFactory to seed cookies with that auth result. But it's unsafe too. We need to remember that set method should be called, so it's seems unreliable too

That's the description of case when passing runtime data through method will be uncomfortable, as executionClient has many methods related to the API interaction

The description of case when creating abstractions could end up with many classes:

```
public createIndefiniteProgressTracker(step?: number, initialWorkDone?: number): ProgressTracker<TProgressNotificationResponse> {
        return new IndefiniteProgressTracker(injected-deps..., step, initialWorkDone);
    }

    public createDefiniteProgressTracker(totalWork: number, step?: number, initialWorkDone?: number): ProgressTracker<TProgressNotificationResponse> {
        return new DefiniteProgressTracker(injected-deps..., totalWork, step, initialWorkDone);
    }
```

This case also could be solved by passing these params to a method - track(...args): void
But it seems to me that passing the data like totalWork, step and initialWorkDone is necessary only once (c-tor or factory) and redundant in every method call

Update 2:
I have an idea to deal with auth in some way:

```
abstract class AuthManager <- IAuthManager
c-tor(IAuthenticator authenticator)
public auth(){authResult = authenticator.auth(...); saveAuthResult(authResult)};
protected saveAuthResult(authResult);
```

```
MyAuthManager <- AuthManager
c-tor(IAuthResStorage storage);
protected saveAuthResult(authResult){storage.save(authResult)};
```

And later I can use IAuthResStorage to get auth data

Comment: Modern IOC containers can act as factories and perform the role of `AFactory` in example 2. The IOC container already has the objects that you would pass to the `AFactory` constructor, so you can add a method to the container which accepts the runtime arguments only and returns class `A`. The syntax to do this will vary based on the container.

Comment: The root of the problem seems that you want to inject *runtime data* into the constructor of a component/injectable. This is a [code smell](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/). If you change the design to prevent letting your component depend on runtime data during construction, you can solve the problem elegantly without the need for introducing temporal coupling (through the `Init` method) or the use of [Abstract Factories](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/).

Comment: @Steven thanks for your links, that's a good read
I find the first link suitable to my issue, but I have some questions about solutions. I wrote them down in the updated description to my question.

Comment: It's hard to recommend anything, because your code sample is very generic, and your real code seems way more complex. One thing that triggers me though is that you state that a "class could have many methods". This sounds like your classes are big, which might indicate a SRP violation. But either way, you'll have to share much more realistic example for us to give better feedback and recommendations.

Comment: @Steven got it, added more detailed code :)

Comment: @Steven, I have an assumption to solve issue with auth object, what do you think about it?
But I didn't come up with an elegant solution of ProgressTracker creation yet :(

Comment: A "progress tracker" is something I usually design similar to what I described in the second example [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/) (with the `IUserContext` injected into the `CustomerRepository`). It gives many components access to the data, without having to pollute the API of objects many layers deep. But as I described [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/ccm/), using a DI Container, this almost always leads to [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) (i.e. an `Init` method).

Comment: @Steven imagine the situation when progress tracker is used in many places with different params. Each set of params will be declared in a type, which will be injected. So, the more sets of params - the more types. It could be ended up with dozen of types which is not very good in this case. Is this the only one flexible and right way to solve this issue in that case? Btw, forgot to mention that one of that params depends on the 3rd party API response, so it is pure-dynamic and unpredictable

Comment: Hi Arty, I don't have a good solution for your quest. What I can advise is, given all the different ideas and information presented here, write a few prototypes for your application and see what works out best.